# How do I interpret this proj4string and why doesn't changing units change its resuls?

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, proj, north-america

I'm new to GIS - I have a background in statistics. I have the following proj4string:

```
'+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0'
```

Can someone explain:

1. What the parameters mean (I think lcc means 'lambert conic conformal')
2. Where I should go to learn how this works/what projections are available?
3. The input lat, lon coordinates are in decimal degrees. What are the output units? The +units=us-ft suggests feet
4. I want to focus my analyses on Manhattan, Brooklyn, Queens, the Bronx. As part of my analysis, I want to split my projected map into a grid. Ideally, each cell will be, say, 1/10th a mile square. What projection should I use for this sort of work? Is LCC acceptable?

Comment: LCC is [Lambert Conformal Conic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection), but close enough ;)

Comment: Answer on question #2 (where to find information on proj4strings): You may find some useful info here: http://proj4.org/

Answer (score 1):

Please keep the site order to put only one question at a time.

https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms will show you what the Proj.4 parameters mean.

If you have input and output, you have to define projections on both sides. Changing the proj.4 definition does **not** change the coordinates automatically. Instead, you make simply 12 meters out of formerly 12 degrees. This is not what you intend.

For coordinates, use `cs2cs`, for vector data `ogr2ogr`, and for raster data `gdalwarp`.

Your 4th item should better be another question.

Comment: sorry I don't follow "If you have input and output, you have to define projections on both sides. Changing the proj.4 definition does not change the coordinates automatically. Instead, you make simply 12 meters out of formerly 12 degrees" As I 'understand' it my proj4string lets me map coordinates in decimal degrees to some projection, which seems to have horizontal units in feet? Could you explain more fully please?

Comment: The string only says that map coordinates are us-feet. No word about decimal degrees coordinates. If you have degrees and want to get feet, you have to reproject your data using one of the three tools I mentioned. There you can say that the input source CRS is WGS84, NAD83 or NAD27 in degrees, and what you want as target CRS.